# ¿Cómo convertir string[] a int? C#

Tags: c#

¡Hola gente! estoy haciendo una gráfica (con chart) que toma información de un archivo de texto para los ejes X,Y. mi problema es al buscar en un archivo de texto, números.

la estructura de mi archivo txt es la siguiente:

int n_encuesta;string ciudad;int edad;string sexo;

ej:
1;Buenos Aires;25;Femenino

```
 2;Corrientes;19;Masculino

 3;...
```

utilizo Split(';') para omitir mi separador en esa cadena y mi objetivo es capturar la edad de todos los registros, linea por linea en el archivo txt. tengo esto:

```
  StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(@"C:\Usuarios\...");
  List<int> list_edad = new List<int>();
  string[] arreglo_cad;
  string cad = stream.ReadLine();

  while(cad != null)
  {
     arreglo_cad = cad.Split(';');
     list_edad.Add(Convert.ToInt32(arreglo_cad[2]));
     // ...[2] porque es la posicion de las edades
     cad = stream.ReadLine();
  }

  foreach(var item in list_edad)
  {
     if(item >= 16 && item <= 30)
        ++cont1;
     else
        ++cont2;
  }
```

pero la lista no me esta guardando los valores, alguna solución ?

Comment: Que valor se guarda arreglo_cad, explica más da más detalles

Comment: pero si ahí lo puse, **arreglo_cad** guarda un arreglo unidimensional devuelto por _Split(';')_ pero el visual no me deja ver el valor de las variables con el depurador. la manera en que me di cuenta de que la List<int> no está guardando, lo comprobé con la propiedad _Count_ . imprimí un mensaje cuando Count < 0. si arreglo_cad no estuviese guardando, imagino que me arrojaría un error, alguna excepción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con `File.ReadAllLines()` que te retorna todas las lineas como un array de `string`:

```
var lineas = Files.ReadAllLines("c/usuarios/...");

var ints = new List<int>();
foreach(var c in lineas)
{
    int edad = int.Parse(c.Split(';')[2]);
    ints.Add(edad);
}
```

Aqui hecha con Linq:

```
var edades = Files.ReadAllLines(@"c:/usuarios/..")
.Select(x=> x.Split(';')[2])
.Select(int.Parse)
.ToList();
```

Comment: joya! sentencias Linq, es tremendo. gracias bro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas seguro es que estas leyendo mal el archivo
Esta es la forma correcta de leer un archivo txt en c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\ruta\archivo.txt");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contenido del archivo = ");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para salir.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: leo el archivo así como muestro en el 'while()' y funciona joya, el problema es que no guardar la List()<int> pero deja pruebo tu propuesta.